# How to render a form with Users information ( React + Redux )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I've managed to get the users information using axios request. I've also managed to render users info on a view using a component that i created. My problem is that i cant display it on an another component i have created which is called ProfileForm. ProfileForm is used as form for updating the info of the user. I want to set the state on the constractor with the user info.

Also, when i change the values to this.props.user.username etc.. i receive two errors:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `value` is marked as required in
>   `TextFieldGroup`, but its value is `undefined`.
>       in TextFieldGroup (at ProfileForm.js:112)
>       in ProfileForm (at ProfilePage.js:23)

and the second is

> warning.js:36 Warning: TextFieldGroup is changing an uncontrolled
>   input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch
>   from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using
>   a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the
>   component.

```
class ProfileForm extends React.Component
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        passwordConfirmation: '',
        errors: {},
        isLoading: false,
        invalid: false
      };

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }

    render() {
      const { errors } = this.state;
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

          <TextFieldGroup
            error={errors.username}
            placeholder="Username"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={user.username} <-- Here should be the bind
            field="username"
          />
          <TextFieldGroup
            error={errors.email}
            placeholder="Email"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            checkUserExists={this.checkUserExists}
            value={user.email} <-- Here should be the bind
            field="email"
          />
          <TextFieldGroup
            error={errors.password}
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={user.password} <-- Here should be the bind
            field="password"
          />
          <div className="form-group">
                <button disabled={this.state.isLoading || this.state.invalid} className="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block">Update</button>
          </div>
        </form>
    );
  }
}

export default ProfileForm;
```

Here is my ProfilePage

```
class ProfilePage extends React.Component { 
        componentDidMount() {
          this.props.getUser();
        }

        render() {
          const { profileUpdateRequest, addFlashMessage, getUser, isUserExists } = this.props;
          return (
            <div className="row">
                  <div className="row text-center">
                    <UserProfile user={this.props.user} /> <-- This works!!!!
                  </div>
                  <ProfileForm
                      profileUpdateRequest={profileUpdateRequest}
                      addFlashMessage={addFlashMessage}
                      getUser={getUser}
                      user={this.props.user} <--- This doesnt work!!!!
                      isUserExists={isUserExists}
                   />                      
            </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

and my UserProfile which works

```
export default function UserProfile({ user }) {

  const userProfile = (
    <div className="row">
      {user.username} {user.email}
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {userProfile}
    </div>
  );
}
```

My ProfileUpdateAction action

```
export function getUser() {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get('/api/user')
    .then(res => res.data)
    .then(data => dispatch(setUser(data.user)));
  }
}
```

And my reducer

```
import { SET_USER } from '../actions/profileUpdateActions';

export default function user(state = [], action = {}) {
  switch(action.type) { 
    case SET_USER:
      return action.user;
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

My textFieldGroup

```
const TextFieldGroup = ({ field, value, label, error, type, onChange, placeholder, min, checkUserExists, disabled }) => {
      return (
        <div className={classnames("form-group", {'has-error': error})}>
              <label className="control-label">{label}</label>
              <input
                type={type}
                name={field}
                className="form-control"
                value={value}
                min={min}
                onChange={onChange}
                onBlur={checkUserExists}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                disabled={disabled}
              />
              {error && <span className="help-block">{error}</span>}
        </div>
      );
    }

    TextFieldGroup.propTypes = {
      field: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      value: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      label: React.PropTypes.string,
      error: React.PropTypes.string,
      min: React.PropTypes.string,
      disabled: React.PropTypes.bool,
      placeholder: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      type: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      onChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      checkUserExists: React.PropTypes.func
    }
    TextFieldGroup.defaultProps = {
      type: 'text'
    }
    export default TextFieldGroup;
```

Comment: You posted (React + redux) in the header. Could you please post you reducer and actions that apply to this situation.
i.e: I presume `this.props.getUser()` is an action.

Comment: Wouldn't user be on your props object (this.props.user.username)?

Comment: Thats true thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In UserProfile, you're using a stateless component that is passed in props as an argument. In the function params, you destructure user to be its own constant. Thats cool and works well.

However, in UserForm, you have a class-based component. The props object is attached to the object's context (this). So to access it, you need to use `this.props.user`.

Comment: Yeap that definitely works! Thanks a lot! But doing this it raised two errors. The first says that The prop `value` is marked as required in `TextFieldGroup`, but its value is `undefined`. And the second says that the TextFieldGroup is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa) etc.. I will update my question

Comment: The value error occurs because a component doesn't have props when it is first mounted. So TextFieldGroup briefly receives an undefined value until the props are passed in. To combat that, you could make it an optional value, or you could move user to your state and initialize the state to have blank values for the user object. The second error occurs probably because the user fields don't get bound since it is undefined. I believe fixing the first issue will also fix the second. Let me know if it doesn't =).